# Can interactive ebook be done as .pdf export or require Adobe publishing suite?

Tags: adobe-indesign, pdf

Can something like [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T0D4avXwMmM&list=TLCoaOREbB4NU) be accomplished via .pdf export from Adobe InDesign CC, our does it require using the Adobe Publishing Suite?

Comment: This is a link to a magazin, smells for spam. What do you mean with "this"? Please add what you want in words to your question ...

Comment: Not spam... just brand new to Adobe InDesign, and creating ebooks in general. Will definitely keep that in mind for the future though.

Comment: @Chad You can edit your question to contain more information.

Answer (score 4):

Ebooks... epub format... are essentially self-contained web sites. The structure within the epub file is very, very similar to a web site's structure. To this end, if you can do something on the web you could create something similar with indesign by exporting to **epub** format then editing the epub further if needed.

However, PDF documents aren't constructed the same way epub documents are. You simply can't create some of the navigation and transitions possible in epub within a PDF format. For example, PDFs are all left to right or bottom to top navigation. you can't do navigation which moves right, right, down, right, up. It's left/right or top/bottom and no mix of the two.

While PDFs do offer the ability to include mixed media and transitions, they simply aren't as malleable as epub documents are.

Adobe Indesign CC has the ability to export to epub format as well as PDF in addition to the ability to configure alternative layouts within a single Indesign document (for portrait/landscape adjustments).

Many publishers build their own **applications** for digital editions. This allows them more freedom overall. Mobile applications can also be constructed very similar to standard web pages with the additional ability to interact with the host operating system. This gives the ability to push updates or new editions where epub will not. Wired Magazine is not using PDFs. They are using either epub or a custom application for digital editions.

Comment: Great answer, thank you. I'm looking to create ebooks and would like to put swipe-able photo galleries, pinch and zoom photos, and possibly audio/video inside them. While not as interactive as an app, I don't think I need that much interactivity for my ebooks. How widely supported are ebooks? Can one published ebook be read from pretty much any mobile device or is an epub reader required?

Answer (score 3):

Simple answer: no.  A `.pdf` is different than a `.epub` per the title of this question.  However both can be viewed in many e-readers.  Furthermore, interactivity is based on device requirements.

Also, you posted a video to Wire's **app** and not an **epub**.  There are limitations to ebooks compared to apps when interactivity is wanted.  This is why many offer apps instead of ebooks for the interactivity and Apple charges more for app release than book release.

Comment: Makes sense. In essence, I will be creating ebooks, in what looks like epub format, that will be sold on Gumroad.com. I'm new to creating ebooks, your answer helped a ton. Thanks!